# Is this result already a known theorem in geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area, quadrilateral

I have been playing around with geometry and I found that:

Let two perpendicular lines intersect at a point that is inside a circle. Then the area of the quadrilateral formed by the vertices made by the lines cutting the circle is half of the product of the perpendicular chords' lengths. Like this:

[image]

Is this already a theorem or at least discovered? If so, what is the name of it?

If someone wants the proof:
[image]

Comment: Yes it is well-known that the area of any quadrilateral is $\frac12pq\sin\theta$, where $p,q$ are diagonals, $\theta$ the angle between them.

Comment: However, still a good job done on this proof! Don't feel disheartened, you will discover more things in the day to come!

Comment: @user10354138 which angle should I use?

Comment: Oh! I just realized that sin(x) and sin(180º-x) are equal. Thanks.

Comment: There is an error in the proof: in the last line, I meant to say: 1/2*AB*CD, not 1/2*AB*BC.